# Next.js revalidate (on-demand) with manual caching

Tags: javascript, caching, next.js

#### Summary

NextJS has the neat feature called [on-demand revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/revalidating#on-demand-revalidation) which I would like to use, but I have an issue.

I'm using Sanity as my CMS, and Sanity has their own client for fetching data. But how can I add a tag revalidation to Sanity, which doesn't use `fetch`?

I was able to cache the data by wrapping my API functions in React's `cache` function, as recommended by [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching#react-cache).

This is an example of one of said functions:

```js
// sanity/api.ts

export const getPosts = cache(
  async (params?: GetPostsParams): Promise<Post[]> => {
    const { labKey } = params || {};

    const query = `...`;

    const posts = await sanity.fetch(query);
    return posts;
  }
);
```

Logically, I should be able to do something like this, but obviously these don't work:

```js
// sanity/api.ts

export const getPosts = cache(
  async (params?: GetPostsParams): Promise<Post[]> => {
    const { labKey } = params || {};

    const query = `...`;

    const posts = await sanity.fetch(query, { next: { tags: ['posts'] }); // this doesn't work
    return posts;
  }
, { next: { tags: ['posts'] }); // this doesn't work either
```

PS: I'm using the new `/app` structure, if that is of any importance

Comment: As a last resort, I'll have to wrap this logic in a Next.js API route, and then just add revalidation to that route by using fetch. This 'solution' is an overhead proxy though that I don't like but I cannot come up with anything else. Manual caching should obviously also support manual revalidation.